# How can I prevent my Django Model from creating a "deferred attribute" for one of my model columns?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Below is my model for "RunCounts"

```
 class RunCounts(models.Model):
    AccountUsername = models.TextField(blank = True)
    RunDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    Report = models.TextField(blank = False)
```

When I later try to reference this in my views.py I cannot filter on the RunDate like I can all the other values in the model. Below is an example of me attempting to filter on it.

`test = RunCounts.objects.filter(RunCounts.RunDate >= '2022-07-13')`

returns the error: '>=' not supported between instances of 'DeferredAttribute' and 'str'

how can I either prevent django from making my RunDate column a 'DeferredAttribute' or be able to still use it in the filter?

Comment: Normally filtering with another field will not work either. This is more how SqlAlchemy filters, not how Django does that...

Answer (score 0):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
RunCounts.objects.filter(RunDate__gt='2022-07-13')
```

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `run_date` instead of <s>`RunDate`</s>.

Comment: Cant believe that worked that easy. Now I have one additional side question. What I was wanting to have is actually filtering to all dates after a certain date that im generating. This isnt working with the example. What would I need to change? 

`RunCounts.objects.filter(RunDate__gt >= startofweek)`

Comment: @Dobbs760: you can use a `date` object insteade of a string `'2022-07-13'`.